# Using PhpStorm 2016.1. Error while connecting via FTPS - Could not list the contents of folder

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, ftps

I'm on a Mac and using the latest version of PhpStorm 2016.1. I had version 6.0.4 and was having problems connecting via FTPS (I'm using credentials which are working on FileZilla). I looked here and other places online and it said that enabling Passive mode and 'Always use LIST command' should work. But this version did not have the latter. So I decided to upgrade and now I've got the latest version.

I tried connecting again, and this time the option did indeed come up but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error!

Just to be sure, the configuration I have in FileZilla is:

```
Host: ****
Port: 21
Protocol: FTP - File Transfer Protocol
Encryption: Require explicit FTP over TLS
Logon Type: Normal
User: ****
Password: ****
```

Here are the log entries -

2016-08-31 21:38:11,396 [ 431750]  DEBUG - t.connections.RemoteConnection - Opening connection to ftps://www.myfinder.com.au:21/ in @30e0690c
2016-08-31 21:38:11,475 [ 431829]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 220 ATP Login
2016-08-31 21:38:11,475 [ 431829]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - AUTH TLS
2016-08-31 21:38:11,643 [ 431997]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 234 Using authentication type TLS
2016-08-31 21:38:11,843 [ 432197]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - USER datar
2016-08-31 21:38:11,870 [ 432224]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 331 Password required for datar
2016-08-31 21:38:11,871 [ 432225]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - PASS ***
2016-08-31 21:38:11,960 [ 432314]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 230 Logged on
2016-08-31 21:38:11,960 [ 432314]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - TYPE I
2016-08-31 21:38:11,976 [ 432330]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 200 Type set to I
2016-08-31 21:38:11,977 [ 432331]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - PBSZ 0
2016-08-31 21:38:12,070 [ 432424]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 200 PBSZ=0
2016-08-31 21:38:12,070 [ 432424]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - PROT P
2016-08-31 21:38:12,285 [ 432639]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 200 Protection level set to P
2016-08-31 21:38:12,286 [ 432640]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - SYST
2016-08-31 21:38:12,409 [ 432763]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
2016-08-31 21:38:12,410 [ 432764]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - PASV
2016-08-31 21:38:12,480 [ 432834]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 227 Entering Passive Mode (168,1,11,106,199,178)
2016-08-31 21:38:12,509 [ 432863]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - LIST
2016-08-31 21:38:12,583 [ 432937]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
2016-08-31 21:38:12,933 [ 433287]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - QUIT
2016-08-31 21:38:13,021 [ 433375]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 450 TLS session of data connection has not resumed or the session does not match the control connection

Comment: I may only suggest to [collect detailed deployment log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs) and check for any hints afterwards in `idea.log` (`Help | Show Log in...`). You may also browse trough [existing tickets on FTPS subject](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%23%7BPlugin:%20Deployment%20_%20FTP..%7D%20%22FTPS%22) and see if they have any relation to your case:

Comment: P.S. Latest version is **2016.2.1** and not your **2016.1**

Comment: Just got a reply back from the support team. Apparently TLS session resumption is not supported by the latest version which is my connection was dropping out. The support person gave me this link to anyone who wanted to vote on getting the feature enabled - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29129